# Python list-comprehension in R?

Tags: python, r, list-comprehension

I want this in R:

```
fsC=[read.table(x) for x in Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv')]
```

i.e. trying to read the content of each file to a separate vector where vectors belong to a data structure.

**Python**

```
[file(x, 'r').read() for x in glob.glob('./Trial7/*.csv')]
```

or better actually

```
[file(x, 'r') for x in glob.glob('./Trial7/*.csv')]
```

but I think you got the point...

Comment: You don't need the `"./"` in the path.  R should look relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sapply to "map" vectors:

```
sapply(Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv'), read.table) -> fsc
```

Comment: ...what about with this kind of puzzle? `data.frame(Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv'), Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv'))->y; sapply(y,read.table)`, requires some join? Merge is too slow... how can you use that with more complex structures? Python `[...]` is a killer there...

Comment: ...or what about `sapply(Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv'), read.table) -> fsc; [log(x[2]) for x in fsC]`, how can you do that in R?

Comment: Since the return value in each case is a `data.frame`, you can't simplify the output to a vector, so `sapply` returns the same thing as `lapply` here.

Comment: @RichieCotton: `x[2]` selects second column of each read file and `log` takes logarith of each col val -- and then [...] returns each file with a vector to the data structure. Are we understanding it the same way? (I am making this example because should I handle this really with many `sapply(sapply(sappaly(sapply(....)))))` (smell bad)? ...or just `sapply(s[2,], log)` but does it combine the structures?

Comment: Trying to keep this clean, moved it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728518/how-to-access-inner-structures-in-r).

Answer (score 7):

You have two questions here.  First, "given a vector of filenames, how do you read those files into R?".

Here's your list of filenames

```
trial7_files <- Sys.glob("Trial7/*.csv") 
#if you prefer to specify the names using regular expressions, try 
trial7_files <- dir("Trial7", "\\.csv$")
```

As previously noted, `lapply` is the best way of reading in the files.

```
fsC <- lapply(trial7_files, read.csv)
```

This gives you a list of data frames, and leads to your next question. "How do you combine a list of data frames with the same columns into one data frame?"

The standard way to do this is with `do.call` and `rbind`.  First, it's useful to make a note of how many rows there are in each dataset.

```
n_records <- sapply(fsC, nrow)
fsC <- do.call(rbind, fsC)
```

That's your problem solved, though you probably want a column telling you which file each row came from.

```
fsC$source <- rep(trial7_files, n_records)
```

Comment: +1, You can add information about data source by adding line: names(trial7_files) <- trial7_files and names will be populated into rownames of data.frame.

Comment: @WojciechSobala: Yeah, I started with that but those rownames are numbered (rather than the same value for each source), and I thought it would be more useful to have the source as a factor.

Comment: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
Calls: do.call -> <Anonymous> -> rbind -> match.names` at that point of `fsC <- do.call(rbind, fsC)`.