# How to access inner structures in R?

Tags: python, r

I am unable to explain this without python, suppose:

```
a=((((()),(),())*3,((((())))))*2)
```

now how can I get `a[0][2]` in R with similar structure? I am a bit lost how these `x[2,]` etc mean in R --  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727943/164148) I am trying by `x[2,]` to get every second column and keep the structure but R mixes it so now trying to understand how to play with inner structures like above in R.

What about with this kind of structure (using iGraph):

```
 g <- as.undirected(ba.game(100, m=1))
 l <- layout.drl(g, options=list(simmer.attraction=0))
 ## Not run:

 plot(g, layout=l, vertex.size=7, vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]

how can I access the inner structures there? What does `g[96:98]` mean or `g[7]`? `g[7]` seventh somethnig? `g[96:98]` something from dimension 1 or? what about `g[96:98,]`?

Answer (score 3):

Take a little time to read up on the R objects of type "matrix," "dataframe," and "list" .  If you've got a nice, well-behaved :-) collection of values in an N-rank tensor (to use the math terminology), then each element is found by `mydata[i,j,k,l]`  for a 4-th rank.  Typically we call that 4-dimensional matrix, and each index i,j,k,l refers to the row,column,hyperrow,hypercolumn location.  Read the R-help files on `[` , `[[` , `$` to get a good start.
If you've got a 'ragged' collection of values, or collections of different kinds of stuff (numeric, factor, character), then you can build a `list` variable, which is similar-ish to a structure or case in C.

To answer your example question: if `x` is a matrix with N columns, you could get the even-numbered columns with `x[,seq(2,N,by=2)]`

Comment: ...related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754901/the-art-of-r-programming-where-else-could-i-find-the-information/7755770#7755770), about further reading.